# Disabled HTML controls aren't submitted, but readonly works not as planned

Tags: html, forms, http-post, disabled-control

When an HTML form contains fields with `disabled` attribute, these fields aren't submitted in POST request data.

I need the data to be submitted because they could be changed and after that fields might be disabled through JavaScript.

It is suggested to use `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled` and it is a decent replacement, but it does not work for `SELECT` boxes - they still can be changed.

What to do?

Comment: You can use `type="hidden"` if you want to submit it and don't want the user to mess with their values.

Comment: @MightyPork: I want user to see these fields on the screen grayed out and disabled. Or you suggest to have a duplicate hidden fields?

Comment: That would be one solution, if readonly doesn't work. Or you can add some JS to remove the disabled state just before the form is sent.

Comment: @MightyPork: `remove the disabled state just before the form is sent`... You are genius!